# ListStepPlot with two axes of ordinates

Tags: plotting

I have the following vector:

```
t0={1.0023, 1.0023, 1.0023, 1.0023, 0.88191, 0.88191, 0.6682, 0.6682, \
1.25614, 1.25614, -1.20461, -1.20461, -1.20461, -1.20461, -1.05992, \
-1.05992}
```

and I'm trying to build a ListStepPlot with two y-axes, such that the last six negative values can be plotted in the top part of the diagram. Here is my code:

```
d=30;line = Line[{{11, 0}, {11, .32}}]; plot1 = 
ListStepPlot[Normalize@t0, 
PlotRange -> {{0.95, 16.5}, {0.15, 0.32}}, 
ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> d, 
Epilog -> {Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], line}]; plot2 = 
ListStepPlot[Normalize@t0, PlotRange -> {{0.95, 16.5}, {-0.32, 0}}, 
ImageSize -> Large, ImagePadding -> d, Axes -> False, 
Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}]; Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

I would like the plot 2 should be "reflected", that is, the origin of the right y-axes should be at the same level as that of the left y-axes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the desired result in a single `ListStepPlot` using `Abs @ Normalize @ t0` as input and and using `` Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"] `` to reverse the tick labels on the right axis:

```
ListStepPlot[
     Abs @ Normalize @ t0, 
     PlotRange -> All,
     ImageSize -> Large, 
     Epilog -> {Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], line},
     Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}},
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"]}, {Automatic, None}},
     FrameLabel -> {Style[#, 16] &/@ {t, t}, {Style[e, 16], None}}
   ]
```

[image]

**Note:** You can also use `` Charting`FindTicks[- {0, 1}, {0, 1}] `` instead of `` Charting`ScaledTicks["Reverse"] ``, and

```
GridLines -> {{{11,Directive[Opacity[1],Black, Thick, Dashed]}}, None}
```

instead of `Epilog -> ...` to get the same picture.

Comment: how can I add the labels?

Comment: @GaeP, please see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks! another question: I would like to use PlotLegends -> PointLegend["t", 
  LegendMarkers -> Automatic] but it seems doesn't work with ListStepPlot...

Comment: @GaeP, try `PointLegend[ {"t"}, LegendMarkers->{Automatic}]` or `LineLegend[ {"t"}, LegendMarkers->{Automatic}]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you want to do, exactly. Is this what you're looking for?

[image: Plot with right axis reversed.]

If so, this is the code I used:

```
t0 = {1.0023, 1.0023, 1.0023, 1.0023, 0.88191, 0.88191, 0.6682, 
  0.6682, 1.25614, 
  1.25614, -1.20461, -1.20461, -1.20461, -1.20461, -1.05992, \
-1.05992}
d = 30; 
line = Line[{{11, 0}, {11, .32}}]; 
plot1 = ListStepPlot[
    Normalize@t0, 
    PlotRange -> {{0.95, 16.5}, {0.15, 0.32}},
    ImageSize -> Large, 
    ImagePadding -> d, 
    Epilog -> {Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], line}
  ]; 
plot2 = ListStepPlot[
     Normalize@t0, 
     PlotRange -> {{0.95, 16.5}, {-0.32, -0.15}}, 
     ImageSize -> Large, 
     ImagePadding -> d, 
     Axes -> False, 
     Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
     ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}
   ]; 
Overlay[{plot1, plot2}]
```

The only things I changed were the `PlotRange` in `plot2` and I added `ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Reverse"}` to `plot2`.

Comment: Further requests: if I add in plot1 AxesLabel -> {"e","t"}, the x-axes' label overlaps to the ticks of the right y-axes. Moreover, I would like AxesLabel -> { ,"t"} at plot2. How can I do?